# When i use nohup command..Are nohup exit codes same as script return codes

Tags: linux, background-process, nohup, exit-status

I am using below command in one script
abc. Sh

Nohup script1.sh $tablename &

This script1.Sh passes some returncodes based on success/fail
Ex:0-success
99fail

When I use exitstatus=$? .. Will this pass same return codes
Ex:0-success
99fail

Comment: You can only get the exit status of your background job if you `wait` for it. The immediate exit status from starting a background job is always zero. I'm not turning this into a proper answer as I'm uncertain what you are doing and what it is that you want to do.  I'm also uncertain what you mean by "pid return codes" that you mention in the title.

Comment: i am waiting till the process ends and getting status wait $!, still i see my script failing and the exit statsus as 0

Comment: You may want to update your question with some more code that shows exactly what you are doing.  The question does not contain any mentioning of `wait $!` at the moment. Also use the formatting toolbar to format the text as code as appropriate.